# How to know the query is operating on in-memory database or disc database

Tags: oracle, in-memory-database

I am trying to measure the query execution time in oracle 12c for in-memory database against disc based database. At client side, I am using JDBC to fire the query.

How do I know that whether the query looks for required database in in-memory or in disc? Is there any option that tells the oracle db server that look for the database first into **in-memory** and then into **disc**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I know that whether the query looks for required database in in-memory or in disc?

You can see that whether the oracle has looked into the memory or disk for data in the Execution Plan as shown below.

```
SQL> desc t1
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                           VARCHAR2(20)
 COL2                           VARCHAR2(20)

SQL> alter table t1 inmemory;

Table altered.

SQL> explain plan for select * from t1;

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display());
Plan hash value: 3617692013

------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |      | 1 |    24 | 0   (0)|
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS INMEMORY FULL| T1   | 1 |    24 |        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------

8 rows selected.

SQL> alter table t1 no inmemory;

Table altered.

SQL> explain plan for select * from t1;

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display());
Plan hash value: 3617692013

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation     | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |  |     1 |    24 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T1   |     1 |    24 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

8 rows selected.
```

> Is there any option that tells the oracle db server that look for the database first into in-memory and then into disc?

Oracle Doc says-

> `INMEMORY`_QUERY is used to enable or disable in-memory queries for the entire database at the session or system level. This parameter is helpful when you want to test workloads with and without the use of the In-Memory Column Store (IM column store).

You disable the in-memory query as:

```
SQL> alter session set inmemory_query = disable;
```

You give `INMEMORY` hint to optimizer to look into the memory for the data as shown below.

```
select /*+ INMEMORY */ * from t1;
```